# Flutter: Fatal signal 31 - crash

Tags: flutter

Lately I experienced several crashes on different places and have not been able to reproduce, so far.

**[Additional information: it seems to only happen in DEBUG mode]**

I am running on Windows 10.

My application uses WebView which also causes many log entries such as:

```
W/zygote  (30629): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Usually, the crash occurs after the following course of actions:

- Facebook authentication (using WebView)
- Dialog to communicate with my server
- pop of the dialog
- new Future.delayed(1 second)  [*I put this to make sure the pop of the previous dialog was complete*]

  - Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(...))

The crash logs the following:

```
F/libc    (30629): Fatal signal 31 (SIGSYS), code 1 in tid 30659 (1.ui), pid 30629 (mobiletest)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM1.180201.007/4586646:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 30629, tid: 30659, name: 1.ui  >>> com.site.mobiletest <<<
signal 31 (SIGSYS), code 1 (SYS_SECCOMP), fault addr --------
Cause: seccomp prevented call to disallowed x86 system call 7
eax 00000007  ebx 00007888  ecx ab4c9b94  edx 40000000
esi 00007888  edi 00000000
xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
eip 97da2289  ebp ab4c9ba8  esp ab4c9b2c  flags 00000282
backtrace:
#00 pc 03fcf289  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (offset 0xa2f000)
#01 pc 03fcedc9  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (offset 0xa2f000)

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:8.1.0/OSM1.180201.007/4586646:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 30856, tid: 30856, name: 1.ui  >>> com.site.mobiletest <<<
signal 31 (SIGSYS), code 1 (SYS_SECCOMP), fault addr --------
Cause: seccomp prevented call to disallowed x86 system call 7
eax 00000007  ebx 000077a5  ecx 00000000  edx 40000000
esi 000077a5  edi 00000000
xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
eip 97da5c87  ebp ab63a998  esp ab63a92c  flags 00000246
backtrace:
#00 pc 03fd2c87  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (offset 0xa2f000)
#01 pc 03fcfb77  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk (offset 0xa2f000)
#02 pc ffff0021  <unknown>
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Here is the output of flutter -doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.3.2 at d:\flutter
    • Framework revision 44b7e7d3f4 (3 weeks ago), 2018-04-20 01:02:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 09d05a3891
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\boeledi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 24.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.23.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Dart Code extension version 2.12.1

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Last comments (I don't know if this could be related):

Since I upgraded Flutter to version 0.3.2, I also experience many issues with the **Hot Reload** with Visual Studio Code (with Android Studio, less issues).
The hot reload does not complete... and I have to stop/restart the application manually.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: There should be a newer beta version. Hot reload improved recently with dev channel for me

Comment: Could the current 0.3.2 version be the cause of the crash?  Because, this crash slows my development very much.  Many times the Simulator freezes during changes in the Navigator (e.g. a new MaterialPageRoute might stop in the middle of the viewport and the Simulator is no longer responding...)

Comment: I had such hot reload issues the recent weeks with dev channel but became stable again a few days ago, so it's possible that this version has this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just moved to the beta channel 0.3.2 about 4 or 5 days ago and have the same experience with Hot Reload. It was working perfectly before I updated the Flutter SDK.

I get the same "The hot reload does not complete... and I have to stop/restart the application manually." as well. I am on beta v0.4.4 and the problem still exists, though I do seem to be able to Hot Reload once or twice before it stops working and I need to restart the debug build.

[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-NZ)